# Simple HTTP GET not working with https to get JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, angularjs

I have this working PhoneGap application built with AngularJS and Onsen UI, that accesses a PHP file where it gets some data in the response. The php file was on a domain with simple http, but now that I moved it to one that supports https , I keep bumping into some weird problems.

I tried the AngularJS async way of getting data, and also an ajax call.

```
$http.get('https://blablabla.com/file.php?parameters').then(function(response) {
        //SUCCESS
        alert(response);
        var z = response;
    },function(response) {
        alert("Failed");
});
```

It goes to the SUCCESS part, but the data that I have in it is incorrect. It should be a string (a plain JSON string, that I will stringify and convert to a json object)

The ajax call is the following:

```
function httpGet(theUrl) {
    var dataToReturn;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: theUrl,
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        data: "",
        success: function(data, textStatus, result) {
            dataToReturn = data;
        },
        error: function (result, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Failed to get response from server!");
        }
    });

    return dataToReturn;
    //var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
    //xmlHttp.send( null );
    //return xmlHttp.responseText;
};
```

I'm basically calling a php script that is in https, from a PhoneGap app.
If I change the address to http, it works flawlessly...

I also want you to note, that PhoneGap basically creates some sort of local proxy. I'm not really sure how to elaborate on this, though...

Any ideas on how to solve this, to get the same data as I would when the addresses are simple "http"?

Comment: You may need to check that the PhoneGap proxy works on port 443.  It sounds like it's already working on port 80, since you have no problems there.  Https uses port 443, so be sure the proxy is configured to work on both ports.

Comment: You may want to read the [`Same origin policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: Can you include samples of the data returned for HTTP and HTTPS in your question? Also, have you tried using your browser network tools or something like Fiddler to examine the requests?

Answer (score 0):

Angular automatically converts json, better if you set the proper header from your PHP serverside:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

just before the echo.

Second your get seems to be missing a parenthesis

```
$http.get('https://blablabla.com/file.php?parameters')
    .then(function(response) {
        //SUCCESS
        alert(response);
        var z = response;
    },function(response) {
        alert("Failed");
    });
```

Third, the response doesn't go straight on response anymore but `response.data`
so you might want to try

```
alert(response.data);
var z = response.data;
```

Warning! this varies a lot depending on your Angular.js version

there are several different syntaxes to use for the $http object depending on the angular version you're on.